# Test two scala shapeless HList types for equivalence via implicit

Tags: scala, shapeless, implicits

I'm interested in testing whether two HList heterogeneous records are "equivalent"; that is, they have the same key/val pairs, but not necessarily in the same order. Is there a predefined type predicate that does what `EquivHLists` does in the code fragment below?

```
// shapeless heterogeneous records with "equivalent" types.
// these should compile if given as the arguments to 'f' below.
val hrec1 = ("a" ->> 1) :: ("b" ->> 2) :: HNil
val hrec2 = ("b" ->> 2) :: ("a" ->> 1) :: HNil

// only compiles if two HList records contain same information
def f(hr1: H1 <: HList, hr2 : H2 <: HList)(implicit equiv: EquivHLists[H1, H2]) = {
  // biz logic
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `Align[M,L]` typeclass supports what you want, it lets you rearrange the elements of one hlist to match the order of another with the same types.

Here's a function that I think does what you want.  It will tell you if two equivalent hlists have the same values for each type.  If the two lists don't have the same types, it won't compile.

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist._

def equiv[H <: HList, L <: HList]
  (h : H, l : L)(implicit align: Align[H, L]): Boolean = align(h) == l

scala> equiv(3 :: "hello" :: HNil, "hello" :: 3 :: HNil)
res11: Boolean = true

scala> equiv(4 :: "hello" :: HNil, "hello" :: 3 :: HNil)
res12: Boolean = false

scala> equiv(4 :: "hello" :: HNil, "hello" :: 3.0 :: HNil)
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter align: shapeless.ops.hlist.Align[Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil,String :: Double :: shapeless.HNil]
```

**edit** : after some further experimentation, this will give false negatives if the hlists have more than one value of the same type:

```
scala> equiv(3 :: "hello" :: 4 :: HNil, 4 :: "hello" :: 3 :: HNil)
res14: Boolean = false
```

This is because of the way `Align` works: it basically just iterates over one hlist and pulls out the first element of the other with the same type.  But if you're using singleton-typed literals then this shouldn't be an issue.

So this *does* work with the above records at least in regards to the keys:

```
scala> equiv(hrec1, hrec2)
res16: Boolean = true

//change one of the keys
scala> val hrec3 = ("c" ->> 2) :: ("a" ->> 1) :: HNil
hrec3: Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("c"),Int] :: Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("a"),Int] :: shapeless.HNil = 2 :: 1 :: HNil

scala> equiv(hrec1, hrec3)
<console>:27: error: could not find implicit value for parameter align ...

//change one of the values, it compiles but returns false
scala> val hrec4 = ("b" ->> 2) :: ("a" ->> 3) :: HNil
hrec4: Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("b"),Int] :: Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[String("a"),Int] :: shapeless.HNil = 2 :: 3 :: HNil

scala> equiv(hrec1, hrec4)
res18: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I may be able to make that work for me. Does `Align` require both HLists to have same number of entries?  Also, was hoping it could be "singleton-aware", that is in `res12` above my pipe dream is it fails instead of returns false, since 4 and 3 would have differing singleton types.

Comment: They do need to have the same number of entries.  Also, see my edit, it is singleton aware for the keys.  I imagine it would work for the values as well if you made them singleton-typed literals.

Comment: In my case a "false" negative is probably what I want. At any rate, this is probably close enough to get me to a solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(hr1: H1 <: HList, hr2 : H2 <: HList)(implicit equiv: H1 =:= H2) = {
  // biz logic
}
```

I believe this should do what you want, have you tried it?

Comment: My understanding of `=:=` is that it tests for types that are exactly equal, which H1 and H2 may not be. Has it been re-defined for shapeless?

Comment: What is the difference from your view-point between equivalent and exactly equal types? I don't think there should be any

Comment: In the example above, `hrec1` and `hrec2` have different types as far as scala is concerned, since their tuples are in different orders, and they are typed using singleton-types.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice that. Maybe expand your code example to demonstrate what you intend.

Comment: What you refer as equivalent is not actually so, in the same sense that List(1,2) =/= List(2,1)